# Access scanner with twain programmatically on windows

Tags: twain

How can I acquire an image using twain on windows without any GUI component involved(Data source manager).
I tried using twain according to following tutorial "https://today.java.net/article/2004/11/16/java-tech-acquire-images-twain-and-sane-part-1" what it does is pops up and interface to select scanner and perform scanning.
 But I need to acquire image programmatically without any user interaction. How can I do that? I prefer C++

Answer (score 0):

You can disable **DAT_USERINTERFACE** to hide the user interface of the device.

Check out this article for C++  TWAIN: [A C++ Wrapper for TWAIN](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296/A-C-Wrapper-for-TWAIN)

Answer (score 0):

You can set  ShowUI to FALSE. Like below:

```
  TW_USERINTERFACE ui;
   ui.ShowUI = FALSE;
   ui.ModalUI = TRUE;
   ui.hParent = hwnd;

// Enable the default data source.
   rc = (*g_pDSM_Entry) (&g_AppID,
                           &srcID,
                           DG_CONTROL,
                           DAT_USERINTERFACE,
                           MSG_ENABLEDS,
                           &ui);
```